# Add image to targets folder by code

Tags: iphone, xcode

i want to add a image to the iphone application Targets-Copy Bundle Resource folder by using code,can make it?any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to add images to your built application, so they're available at runtime? In this case, just drag them to your Project tree and make sure your target is checked in the Add dialog. If they're already in your project, but aren't currently in the Copy Bundle Resources, you can drag them there from the file tree.